# Class name as a variable in python

Tags: python

I was just looking at one question here and the OP was using a same name for class, other things and also for variable. When I was trying to answer it, I became confused myself and thus thought of asking.

For example:

```
class MyClass:
      pass

MyClass=MyClass()
```

Though, I will never code anything like this. I would like to understand how this will be treated by python interpreter. So my question is, is the variable MyClass I will use will be created first or the other way? Which is, creating an instance of MyClass firstly and assigning it to MyClass variable. I think the latter is correct but if that is the case, how will the following be resolved?

```
class MyClass:
      pass

MyClass=MyClass()
new_class=MyClass()
```

Comment: Try it out yourself. You would get something like `AttributeError: MyClass instance has no __call__ method` because now, you are calling the instance, rather than the class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class MyClass:
    pass

MyClass=MyClass()
```

In simple terms, the above code does three things (in this order):

1. Defines the class `MyClass`.
2. Creates an instance of `MyClass`.
3. Assigns that instance to the variable `MyClass`.

After the last step, the class `MyClass` is overwritten and can no longer be used.  All you have left is an instance of it contained in the variable `MyClass`.

Moreover, if you try to call this instance as you would a class, you will get an error:

```
>>> class MyClass:
...     pass
...
>>> MyClass=MyClass()
>>> new_class=MyClass()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'MyClass' object is not callable
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

The right-hand side of the assignment is processed first, so an instance of `MyClass` is created. But then you reassign the name `MyClass` to that instance. When you execute

```
new_class = MyClass()
```

you should get an error about `MyClass` not being callable, since that name now refers to an instance of the original class, not the class itself.

Answer (score 2):

The line:

```
new_class=MyClass()
```

in most cases will return an error, saying something like instance not callable.

`MyClass` now refers to the instance of what `MyClass` previous held that is a class.

You could make a new instance of *former* `MyClass` by:

```
new_class = MyClass.__class__()
```

`MyClass` is just just a variable that points/refers to a particular object. First it was class then it was changed to hold an instance of that `class`.

Answer (score -1):

Variables are treated as objects in Python. From my understanding, when you assign a new instance of MyClass to an object, python will try to create a reference of the original class to the object and duplicate. However, the namespace of the new object is already used (in the original MyClass), and the duplication will return you an error, so the first code will not work.

For the second piece of code, the final line will not execute due to the same reason of Namespace Duplication. Since the last but one line failed, the proposed reference target is still the original MyClass, which won't work at all.

Comment: I think you can go back to 1/ the FineManual(tm) and 2/ your Python shell.